# Decrementing a field of type number in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm learning mongodb.
I have a collection called **item** which has a field `piecesLeft` of a type Number, and I want to decrement this field value when a user orders this particular item. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator.

```
 db.yourcollection.update({ /* find options */ }, { $inc: {piecesLeft : -1 } });
```

**Updated:**

```
db.yourcollection.update({
    _id: '572f16440a0dbb1e0cc02201', // Find updated item e.g. by _id
    piecesLeft: { $gt: 0 } // Update only if piecesLeft > 0
}, {
    $inc: {
        piecesLeft: -1 // Increment by -1 
    }
});
```

Comment: what do u mean by options? and why did you downvote my question? I'm new and trying to learn. Also, I've searched and didn't find an answer in my situation.

Comment: First argument is search criteria for an updated record in the collection.  
e.g. `{ _id: '572f16440a0dbb1e0cc02201' }`.