# update mongoDB: decrement quantity

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Bike.update({
        _id: req.params.id,
        quantity: { $gt: 0},
    }, {
        $inc: {
            quantity: -1
        }
    })
    res.redirect('/products');
});
```

I want to decrement the quantity of this bike after the user selects the "add to cart" button. The documentation for my class suggests submitting a form that includes every property in the schema. Each property would remain the same except for quantity, which would decrement. I tried that approach without success. Here's a link to a solution I looked up that involved running code similar to the code I have added above:

[Decrementing a field of type number in mongodb and nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544679/decrementing-a-field-of-type-number-in-mongodb-and-nodejs)

However, the quantity doesn't decrement using this solution either

Comment: Have you tested the update method to ensure you are first returning a document?

Comment: req.params.id is usually a string.  Is the `_id` field also, or is it ObjectId?

Comment: @Joe Good Point. The _id field is ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

req.params.id is a string to compare objected against a string in MongoDB you should write .includes.
This Should Work

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Bike.update({
        _id.includes(req.params.id),
        quantity: { $gt: 0},
    }, {
        $inc: {
            quantity: -1
        }
    })
    res.redirect('/products');
});
```